# Locating a Span jQuery Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to find a jQuery code that controls a span element in my template.

For example:

```
<span class="ccontent"
```

- That class opens a info window when hovered upon.

How can i find the jQuery code that relates to this in my template using Chrome and in what file it resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, right click and select "Inspect Element" to open up your inspector. On a Mac you can use  Command + Option + I

After that click Resources tab, then Command + F (again, Mac, not sure about PC). Type ccontent into the search box and you will see the number of references to that class-name. Click through until you see all the places in your code where it's mentioned.

Comment: Only downfall is if they're selecting that span via DOM traversal like `$('#divID').find('span')` or `$(this).prev()`, etc

Comment: Syon, so very true, and I do that a LOT. I like generic code for reuse but it does make it hard to follow sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [Visual Event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2)

> Visual Event is an open source Javascript bookmarklet which provides debugging information about events that have been attached to DOM elements. Visual Event shows:
>
> - Which elements have events attached to them
> - The type of events attached to an element
> - The code that will be run with the event is triggered
> - The source file and line number for where the attached function was defined (Webkit browsers and Opera only)

Comment: thanx m8..but Matthew's answer was just what i was looking for because i work with Chrome dev tools

Comment: @Syon - Thanks for the link. I've added it to my chrome. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Matthew Davis will work when you can search through your code for the id (e.g. "#ccontent") in question, but won't work as well when the element is indirectly referred to e.g. by class or by element type.

The Visual Events bookmarklet will also help you, but sometimes it will just list the minified JQuery code for the event that is bound to the element.

When doing a mouseover or something else that results in a change to the DOM or a change to an attribute of the thing you are hovering over, and the first two (easier!) options fail, you can try the following:

- Go into the Elements tab of the Chrome Developer tools (CTRL+SHIFT+I).
- If you are interested in tracking the attributes changing of an element, right click on it and click "Break On > Attributes modifications":

[image: AttribModification]

- If you are interested in something changing in the DOM (e.g. a modal appearing), right click on the body of the document, or the relevant container div, and click "Break On > Subtree modifications":

[image: SubtreeModification]

- Then do your mouseover or trigger whatever event you are interested in on the element.
- The Chrome Debugger should launch, and on the right-hand side is the Call stack:

[image: CallStack]

- You can click on the different items in the call stack to see where a call was triggered in the Source tab.